# How to ensure application/hal+json is the first supported media type

Tags: spring-hateoas

I have created a Hateoas enabled Rest service using spring-boot-starter-data-rest, works well.
I then created a client of that rest service in another spring boot module: this is a dependency that can be included in other projects that want to use the rest service. It uses a restTemplate under the hood. 
It took a bit of mucking around with HttpMessageConverters and TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to get it to work but it does.

I tried using this dependency in my main application but it failed to populate the links in ResponseEntity< Resource< Myclass> >, leading to null pointer exceptions.

I couldn't track down the problem so I created a basic Spring Boot application 2.1.5.RELEASE and got the client working, then traced back the problem to this configuration in my main application which unfortunately is need for another problem:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

If this configuration is present it seems that hal+json isn't the first accepted media type

```
org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog.debug(CompositeLog.java:147) : Accept=[application/json, application/hal+json, application/octet-stream, application/*+json]
```

When the configuration is removed I see

```
org.springframework.core.log.CompositeLog.debug(CompositeLog.java:147) : Accept=[application/hal+json, application/json, application/octet-stream, application/*+json]
```

and I can see this logged which fixes the issue I assume ( it isn't logged when the error happens)

```
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.hateoas.use-hal-as-default-json-media-type) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

I have tried adding this configuration to force the issue but it doesn't work

```
spring:
  hateoas:
    use-hal-as-default-json-media-type: true
```

This is my code in the rest client to configure the message converters:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageConverterConfiguration {

  @Bean public TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter myhalJacksonHttpMessageConverter(){
    return new TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter( ResourceSupport.class );
  }

  /**
   * Add {@link TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter} to the list of {@link HttpMessageConverter}s
   * configured in the {@link  RestTemplate} in first position ( this position  is critical ).
   * @param halJacksonHttpMessageConverter automagically configured by spring-boot-starter-hateoas
   * @return List of {@link HttpMessageConverter}s
   */
  @Bean( name = "hal-jackson" ) public List< HttpMessageConverter<?> > mymessageConverters( TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter halJacksonHttpMessageConverter ) {

    final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> all = new ArrayList<>(  );
    all.add( halJacksonHttpMessageConverter );
    all.add( jacksonConverterWithOctetStreamSupport( ) );
    all.addAll( new RestTemplate().getMessageConverters() );

    return all;
  }

  /**
   * This allows converting octet stream responses into {@link LastApplicationRun} ,
   * when we create a last run by posting with {@link RestTemplate#postForObject(URI , Object, Class)}
   * : without it we get a
   * <pre>org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter
   * found for response type [class com.sparknz.ced.spark.sampling.rest.tobesampled.client.domain.LastApplicationRun]
   * and content type [application/octet-stream]</pre>.
   * <p></p>
   * I could find no better solution: it is not needed when we make a get call, don't understand why we get an octet stream response.
   * It may only now be useful for tests.
   */
  private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonConverterWithOctetStreamSupport( ) {

    final MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

    converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(
        asList(new MediaType[]{
            MediaType.valueOf( "application/hal+json" ) ,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM }));

    return converter;
  }

}
```

What is 'web-application-type: none' doing and how can I get HypermediaHttpMessageConverterConfiguration to run?

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding this to my configuration class did the trick:
    @Import( RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class )

RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration seems to be responsible for making hal+json the highest priority by adding RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.ResourceSupportHttpMessageConverter at position 0 in the list of HttpMessageConverters.